# Why is this regex replace function creating line breaks in my html body?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to replace hashtags in the body of an html page with a Bootstrap4 Modal. 
Sometimes, this function causes line breaks right after the replaced text link. Sometimes it doesn't. I don't understand why.

```
function replaceBlank() {

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/#blank/g, '' +
'<a data-target="#blankMod" data-toggle="modal" href="#">' +
    'Blank' +
'</a>' +
'<div class="modal fade" id="blankMod">' +
    '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
        '<div class="modal-content">' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
                '<h4 class="modal-title">' +
                    'Blank' +
                '</h4>' +
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">' +
                    'x' +
                '</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">' +
                'Blank Text Body' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>');

}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the the HTML you try to replace? Particularly, one that has a problem?

Comment: On a separate note, have you considered *not* using a string replacement to manipulate the DOM but actually use DOM manipulation methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the line breaks only occurred within paragraph `<p>` tags.
The replacement text was ending the `<p>` tag, and everything after it was considered a new paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever run it more than once on the same page?

The text you are inserting contains the string you are replacing (the `data-target="#blankMod"` bit).

You are using the `/g` flag, so multiple replaces *in one step* will still work fine; but the second time you call it, it is bound to go a bit crazy.

If that is the problem, you could either stop using that data-target name, or you could capture a bit more context of where "#blank" appears in your document. (lookbehind/lookahead regex asserts are ideal for this, but require the latest versions of JavaScript, so may give browser compatibility issues.)

Comment: "*you could either stop using that data-target name, or you could capture a bit more context of where "#blank" appears in your document.*" or OP can use proper DOM traversal and DOM manipulation, instead of a cobbled together regex solution.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, that might be the "proper" solution. Hard to say without knowing more about the project, the deadline, if this is a quick one-off hack or something that will be in production for the next five years, etc. Definitely worth giving a link in a comment so they can learn more, but I just answered the question as asked. (Well, guess-answered...)

Comment: This is for personal-project to help my local gaming store's role-playing/D&D community track their campaign.

The goal is to replace NPC names with a link to a bootstrap4 modul describing that character,

For example, if someone writes "In session 3, my character Susie Sample met the wandering merchant #mickey and purchased 3 days rations", it would replace #mickey with 'Mickey the Merchant' and if someone clicked the link it would call the modul with a more detailed description of Mickey.

Some limitations: The site has to be static. I can't use PHP. I'm limited to html, css, and js.

Comment: _"The text you are inserting contains the string you are replacing"_. Ha... I will go double check if I actually did that. If so I'm going to eat my shoe.